# Getting page names with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I have a file with a list of links. The links are all in the format of `/pagename.htm`. I'm trying to use `preg_replace_callback` to get all of those page names but the callback function never gets called. I'm sure it has to do with the regex but I don't see how to fix it. Would someone please point out the problem.

```
    return  preg_replace_callback("/^(\/(.*?)\.htm)$/", "HandleLinks", $filenames); 

    function HandleLinks($matches) {   
       echo 'match '.$matches[1].'<br>';
       return $matches;
    }
```

Comment: give me an example string for filenames

Comment: show the `$filenames` contents

Comment: The filenames would be like /bob.htm, /sally.htm, /fred.htm or /anyname.htm. The only things that are constant is that they will start with a / and end with .htm. There will be text before the / and may be some after the .htm. So a string might be, "<a href=""/bob.htm>Bobo</a><a href="/sally.htm">Sally</a>, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the following:

```
    preg_replace_callback("/(\/(.*?)\.htm)/", "HandleLinks", $filenames);
```